# JSON Parsing is not working with Ruby, but is for Python

Tags: python, ruby, json, iis

I am attempting to parse the following example JSON.

```
{'data': {'Application': [{'Name': 'Test1', 'CommVersion': '3.4', 'Version': '3.4.1.765', 'GUID': 'B052A35E-DC3B-4283-B732-7BEE3B095C5E'}, {'Name': 'Test2', 'CommVersion': '0', 'Version': '2.8.2.34', 'GUID': 'F0EE9258-7881-4EA5-89A9-0DE922A37224'}, {'Name': 'Test3', 'CommVersion': '3.0', 'Version': '4.3.2.58', 'GUID': 'C91BDA6E-E678-4FCF-93D8-18308D17D7A3'}, {'Name': 'Test3', 'CommVersion': '0', 'Version': '2.8.7.34', 'GUID': '4449D713-3651-459A-A96E-3E748238848C'}], 'SessionId': 'ltGINZHmfSyVLgu', 'Version': '5.2'}, 'valid': True}
```

In Python, I am doing this by using the Requests module with the code

```
s = requests.get(session_url)
json_decode = s.json()
print(json_decode)
```

This works. In Ruby, I am attempting to do this through the code:

```
uri = URI("https://mywebsite.com")
host = 'mywebsite.com'
port = 443

def getData(siteURI, httpObject)
  request  = Net::HTTP::Get.new siteURI
  response = httpObject.request request 
  return JSON.parse response.body
end

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https',
  verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
  data = getData(setupSessionURI, http) 
  puts data
end
```

However, whenever I run this, I get

```
<Json::ParserError> in 'parse' : 776 : Unexpected Token
```

then I see a bunch of HTML below it.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am not a Ruby programmer and I am trying to translate my Python script. I don't believe anything is wrong with the JSON.

Comment: The example you gave us isn't JSON. Its the python that results from decoding the JSON. Since you are trying to puzzle out JSON decode in ruby, it would be helpful to post the JSON string that is giving the problem.

Comment: _"Then I see a bunch of HTML..."_ - So the ruby code isn't fetching a JSON page at all. Does the html look like an error page? Does the url you use look exactly like the one in python? It looks like there is some session stuff going on... did login fail or perhaps cookies are wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your code for readability, including correct indentation. That helps everyone by making it easier to read and debug your code. The effort you put in directly affects the effort people put in to help you. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: _" I don't believe anything is wrong with the JSON."_ but the parser is telling you that there is a problem with the json exactly on character 776. But still you won't post the string that you are trying to decode. Your example, converted from python to json is 537 characters long. Not 776. Just post the data and then we'll know.

Comment: 776 is not the character number in string. It's a line in ruby code in 'json' library where the Exception is thrown.

Comment: @DracoAter Okay, I don't know ruby so that was just a guess. I think OP is getting an error html page so its really immaterial. Until OP gives us the actual text that can't be decoded its all idle speculation.

Comment: May be. @Trumpetplayer0098, show us the `response.body`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
require 'json'
data = {'data': {'Application': [{'Name': 'Test1', 'CommVersion': '3.4', 'Version': '3.4.1.765', 'GUID': 'B052A35E-DC3B-4283-B732-7BEE3B095C5E'}, {'Name': 'Test2', 'CommVersion': '0', 'Version': '2.8.2.34', 'GUID': 'F0EE9258-7881-4EA5-89A9-0DE922A37224'}, {'Name': 'Test3', 'CommVersion': '3.0', 'Version': '4.3.2.58', 'GUID': 'C91BDA6E-E678-4FCF-93D8-18308D17D7A3'}, {'Name': 'Test3', 'CommVersion': '0', 'Version': '2.8.7.34', 'GUID': '4449D713-3651-459A-A96E-3E748238848C'}], 'SessionId': 'ltGINZHmfSyVLgu', 'Version': '5.2'}, 'valid': 'True'}
JSON.parse(data.to_json)
```

Comment: I tried this. My Ruby JSON parse is now

`def getData(siteURI, httpObject)
    request  = Net::HTTP::Get.new siteURI
    response = httpObject.request request 
    return JSON.parse(response.to_json)}`

When this runs, I receive the Unexpected Token Parse error 776 error again

Comment: It still does not work? What error you get now? The data hash that you posted in the question and that I used in the answer, that works fine the way I showed in my answer.

Comment: Look at edited response above for edited code and error. The parse token error at "#<Net::HTTPOL:0x00000002e8c0b8>"

Comment: `'valid': True` may give you trouble if it's present in the response. I made it this to make it work: `'valid': 'True'` (put the True inside quote as string). Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: This JSON is dynamic and is being produced by a session call, is there a way to write Ruby so that it will make True into 'True'? I won't be able to change the JSON itself.

Comment: If the JSON generated is dynamic and has any invalid token that Ruby can't determine, then I don't think there is any quick way to do this. Because, even if you fix it for `True` there could be other unexpected tokens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97545/discussion-between-trumpetplayer0098-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Comment: I really don't understand the relevancy. So ruby can parse the JSON string ruby itself creates. Does this fact relate to OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your example JSON is not valid json. The valid json should have strings surrounded in double quotes. Indeed when parsing your string you will get the `JSON::ParserError`. But if you substitute all single quotes to double quotes and `True` to `true`, then parsing will succeed.

This one is correct json:

```
{"data": {"Application": [{"Name": "Test1", "CommVersion": "3.4", "Version": "3.4.1.765", "GUID": "B052A35E-DC3B-4283-B732-7BEE3B095C5E"},     {"Name": "Test2", "CommVersion": "0", "Version": "2.8.2.34", "GUID": "F0EE9258-7881-4EA5-89A9-0DE922A37224"},{"Name": "Test3", "CommVersion": "3.0", "Version": "4.3.2.58", "GUID": "C91BDA6E-E678-4FCF-93D8-18308D17D7A3"},{"Name": "Test3", "CommVersion": "0", "Version": "2.8.7.34", "GUID": "4449D713-3651-459A-A96E-3E748238848C"}],"SessionId": "ltGINZHmfSyVLgu","Version": "5.2"},"valid": true}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. OP gave us the python data structure he decoded from one request but has yet to give as an example of the alleged json string causing problems in ruby. I think OP is getting an error page in his ruby code.

Comment: I think the OP tries to parse the provided structure as a string. (Imagine it is surrounded with quotes)

Comment: I think he is showing us the result of the python print statement `print(json_decode)` in the code that works. He needs to show us the input to the script that isn't working. The provided example is not json so the only real answer there would be "fix the web server".